# How to pass command to qemu console at launch?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, qemu

Is there any way to pass qemu console command directly at command launch? I mean passing for example `balloon 2048M` at VM boot. I'm using `qemu-system-x86_64` straight from shell (no `virsh` or any GUI). I'm exposing vms consoles over localhost telnet.

Answer (score -1):

```
chroot <path to your environment> balloon 2048M
```

shall do the job, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157931/bash-executing-commands-from-within-a-chroot-and-switch-user) even with sudo

Comment: Not shell command but QEMU console command. Something like `echo balloon 2048 | nc 127.0.0.1 6000 & ; sleep 2 ; killall nc` which is basically what I did however it's a bit dirty.